# Error while executing .plist file Path had bad ownership/permissions

Tags: terminal, plist

Getting a error while executing the `plist` file in `terminal`

ERROR : `Path had bad ownership/permissions`

1) I created a plist file using `xcode 6` and saved the plist file in path `library/launchdaemons/myfile.plist`

*myfile.plist*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>myfile</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Desktop/myscript.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>14</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>35</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

2) In terminal i used the `sudo launchctl load` command to load the `plist` file

```
sudo launchctl load /library/launchdaemons/myfile.plist
```

3) After that i am getting this error

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/myfile.plist: Path had bad ownership/permissions
```

Where i am going wrong ?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Try changing the ownership of the .plist file:

```
sudo chown root /Library/LaunchDaemons/myfile.plist
sudo chgrp wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/myfile.plist
```

or more simply, change the user and group in one command:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/myfile.plist
```

It is also worth noting that these root `LaunchDaemons` can't be world writable, for security reasons:

```
sudo chmod o-w /Library/LaunchDaemons/*
```

Comment: ya this was the right solution but before 4 days oly i got the solution anyway thank you

Comment: @Vivek you should have shared your solution then.

Comment: @MatterGoal: I was unable to access Stackoverflow on those 4 days when I came back here, I saw the solution posted.

Comment: The permissions error I faced on https://dansketcher.com/2021/03/30/shmmax-error-on-big-sur/ was resolved by this answer. Thanks! 73 de W2IVV/VU3TTL

Comment: staff group is working for me, but the file must not be group writable

Comment: Can you create a 'user' service though? There a Q for that?

Answer (score 20):

The plist file must be owned by root and group wheel as rw only for owner.
So root:wheel 600

Comment: This was crucial for resolving the issue

Comment: mine runs when its group readable with group staff (i.e. 640)

Answer (score 7):

**In addition to the above**

```
sudo chmod 600 /directoryToFile/filename.plist
```

for example:

```
sudo chmod 600 com.backup.plist
```

or

```
sudo chmod 600 /Library/LaunchDaemons/myfile.plist
```

Comment: 640 works as well (i.e. g+r)