# Run terminal command on startup with launchd.plist

Tags: macos, plist, startup, boot, launchd

I was looking for an answer to my question on Stack Overflow and found a thread (https://superuser.com/questions/229773/run-command-on-startup-login-mac-os-x). That's how I found out about `launchd.plist` and I made one myself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>js.leapmotion</string> 
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
            <string>open</string>
            <string>/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app</string>
    </array>
    
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This indeed starts my terminal after booting my Mac. But now I want it to navigate to a directory and run the command `gulp` in there.
This again will do the rest, opens up a localhost and so on...

So in the end I just need to run `gulp` within an specific directory. That's all. If `launchd.plist` is not the best way to go, then I'm open for alternatives.
Otherwise I would like to know how I can tell the terminal what commands it should run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `open` command to open Terminal and run a script by using the `-a` flag. For example, `open -a Terminal /path/to/myscript` will open a new Terminal window and run `myscript`. Note that when `myscript` finishes, the session will terminate (i.e. there's no shell). To change that, you can run `bash` or whatever your preferred shell is as part of the script.

In your case, I would suggest creating a basic script to do whatever you want Terminal to execute, such as :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /path/to/your/directory
/usr/bin/gulp
```

Save that (making sure it's executable), and then change your launchd plist to match:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
        <string>open</string>
        <string>-a</string>
        <string>Terminal</string>
        <string>/path/to/yourscript</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I cannot get it to work. Maybe because I still don't understand too much about shell and bash etc.
I wrote this script as you proposed, and I saved it to filename.command. Is the suffix `command` ok? I also made it executable. with `chmod +x`. In between I had it named `filename.sh`. which did not work either.
If I double click on the file it starts up and runs gulp in the right directory, as expected. I also adapted the launchd plist as you suggested. but this just does not execute after starting up... Anything I forgot?

Comment: Does the Terminal launch at all? If so, can you add to your answer with your script, launchd file and output from the Terminal.

Comment: Sure. As soon as I am back on that machine. Btw; can I somewhere activate email notification about comments? Yesterday I just missed your answer totally.

Comment: Alright I tried again, and the terminal does not start at all and therefore I have no output. I also posted my current plist file and the .command file again in my answer (although my edit needs to be reviewed first. I have no clue who will do that...)
As well I wanted to ask, how important is the `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/some.meaningful.name.plist` command?
Because if I do that, I get: `Path had bad ownership/permissions`
so I got here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063598/error-while-executing-plist-file-path-had-bad-ownership-permissions but this did not help..

Comment: Any launch agent that are for a particular user should go in the user's Library directory (`~/Library/LaunchAgents`), not the system one (`/Library/LaunchAgents `). Similarly, loading the launch agent shouldn't be done with sudo. Just do `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/js.leapmotion.plist` (the filename must match the label in the plist). If you still have problems, look for `launchd` output in Console.app